# Moving $HOME to /local/name123 on RHEL 7.6 (Maipo)

Tags: rhel, home

I don't have root rights on this machine. But I have two directories in which I can do basically everything, the **original home** (/home/name123) has only **1 GB** space and the **/local/name123** has **1 TB** of space. I would like to move my $HOME variable permanently to the partition with 1 TB. Is it enough to just copy all config files to the new location and set $HOME to it or do I have to expect certain problems?

Answer (score 0):

You could copy all directory content with:

```
cp -p -r /home/name123/* /local/name123/
```

-p to preserver permissions and -r to copy folders and everything inside them (recursevely)
You need root permissions to set the new home directory for name123 user:

```
usermod -d /local/name123 name123
```